# cannot assign to `self.tick_data` because it is borrowed

Tags: sockets, rust, rust-tokio

Folks, Rust newbie here. I'm trying to implement a `struct` that behaves like a `class` for listening to websockets (that makes most sense to me, as I'm coming from an OOP background).
This is the struct:

```
pub struct Trader {
    symbols: [String; 2],
    bar_length: Duration,
    last_bar: NaiveDateTime,
    tick_data: DataFrame,
    log_level: LogLevel,
    socket: Option<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>,
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm storing the socket datastream inside the socket field. I've done that so that I can manage connects/disconnects by using a connect function that takes a mutable reference to `self` and sets socket `field`. So far, so good.

Now, I'm also implementing a `listen_events` function in order to listen to websockets messages, parse them and store them in the field `tick_data` (`DataFrame` refers to `polars::prelude`)
As `tungstunite` `WebSocketStream` next method is `async`, I've wrapped its result around a `tokio::select!` `macro`, so that I can listen not only to new messages, but also to intervals or any other events.
Below, you can find my implementation for `listen_events` with all the details mentioned above, and also the `get_socket` function:

```
fn get_socket(&mut self) -> &mut WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>> {
        &mut self.socket.unwrap()
    }

pub async fn listen_events(&mut self) -> Result<(), TError> {
        let socket = self.get_socket();
        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                result = socket.next() => {
                    let message = result.unwrap();
                    let message = message.unwrap();
                    let message_text = message.to_string();
                    if !message_text.contains("\"e\":\"kline\"") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    let kline_response: KlineResponse = serde_json::from_str(&message_text).unwrap();
                    let tick_data = parse_kline_into_df_data(kline_response).unwrap();
                    let tick_data_df = parse_tick_data(tick_data).unwrap();
                    self.tick_data = self.tick_data.vstack(&tick_data_df).expect("vstack failed!");
```

As you Rust veterans can see, in order to receive the async response from socket.next(), socket **must** to be mutable. The problem is that after receiving the websocket message (and parsing it), I need to add it to the `tick_data` field, so that I can process/resample it when convenient. Since socket borrows self as mutable, I can't reassign `tick_data`, as it also is part of self.

Also, please notice that reassigning `tick_data` happens inside the scope of `socket` borrowing (I can't imagine how it could be otherwise). I can't see how wrapping socket in a Rc smart pointer could help me.
I've asked several questions to ChatGpt to no avail.

For me, it makes (little) sense to not be able to edit a field while other is borrowed. On the other hand, it makes (a lot) of sense needing to borrow self as mutable, so that I can borrow socket as mutable.

Any insights on this? Please, help me be a better Rust developer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Folks, as it turns out, developing in typescript gave me the bard habit of treating variables, specially objects and arrays, as references (always).

In Rust, apparently, you have to be extra-cautious when dealing with variables and storing their references. Apparently the code

```
let socket = self.socket.as_mut().unwrap();
        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                ws_message = socket.next() => {
                    let message = ws_message.unwrap();
                    let message = message.unwrap();
                    let message_str = message.to_string();
                    if !message_str.contains("\"e\":\"kline\"") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    let kline_response: KlineResponse = serde_json::from_str(&message_str).unwrap();
                    let tick_data = parse_kline_into_tick_data(kline_response).unwrap();
                    let tick_data_df = parse_tick_data(&tick_data).unwrap();
                    self.tick_data = self.tick_data.vstack(&tick_data_df).expect("vstack failed!");

                    println!("pushed str to buffer");
                }
```

throws no compile-time errors.The getter fn was suggested by ChatGpt, which also turns out that you must to be extra-cautious when dealing with it.